# How create hash with arrays in perl

Tags: perl

I have a script that looped over to get the values ​​$mac and $snr. The result of the loop is as follows

**1**33.3**1**33.5**1**32.9**1**33.1**1**32.9**1**31.8**2**34.4**2**33.7**2**34.7**2**30.3**2**32.3**2**30.8**3**31.9**3**32.0**3**31.6**3**31.6**3**30.9**3**30.2 itd.....
**94**37.3**94**37.0**94**36.7**94**36.8**94**35.1**94**33.09535.29535.

result from $mac is bolt
result form $snr is next

how create %hash where result will be

```
  my %hash = ( mac1 => [’snr1', ‘snr2', ‘snr3', ‘snr4', ‘snr5', ‘snr6'],
                 mac2 =>  [’snr1', ‘snr2', ‘snr3', ‘snr4', ‘snr5', ‘snr6'],
                 mac3 => [’snr1', ‘snr2', ‘snr3', ‘snr4', ‘snr5', ‘snr6'],
                 );
```

result with value

```
 my %hash = ( 1 => [’33.3', ‘33.5', ‘32.9', ‘33.1', ‘32.9','31.8' ‘'],
             2 =>  [’34.4', ‘33.7', ‘34.7', ‘30.3', ‘32.3', ‘30.8'],
             3 => [’31.9', ‘32.0', ‘31.6', ‘31.6', ‘snr5', ‘snr6'],
             );
```

I can put only part code:
I can put only part code:

```
my $db_snr = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$baza:$host", $user, $pass, { RaiseError=>'0', AutoCommit=>'1'} );
        if(! $db_snr){
                print LOG  "Can't connect to mysql serwer at $host, skipping!\n";
                exit 0;
        }
foreach $upstrim (sort keys %interface){
        $typ = $interface{$upstrim}[50];
        $mac=$interface{$upstrim}[0];
        $mac=~ s/MAC//;
        print($snr)
        print($mac) # here I woul like create hash witch array
   if(($typ eq 'u') && ($mac =~ m/^\d/)){
        my $snr = $interface{$upstrim}[30];

        if (($snr < 11) && ($snr > 0)) {
                print LOG "Test SNR nadajcy $cmts:$mac:$snr:$typ\n";
                $db_snr->do("insert into snr values ('$cmts','$mac',NOW(),NOW(),'$snr','1','0','$upstrim') ON DUPLICATE KEY update snr='$snr' ,data_last=NOW(), licznik=licznik+1 ") or warn "Can't prepare: $DBI::errstr";
        }
   }
}
$db_snr->disconnect;

close(LOG);
```

Comment: What is `133.3133.5132.9133.1132.9131.8234.4233.7234.7230.3232.3230.8331.9332.0331.6331.6330.9330.2 itd..... 9437.39437.09436.79436.89435.19433.09535.29535.`? Do you mean to say that all the numbers come mashed together into one long line? Why don't you just show the code you are using?

Comment: Yes, when I print($mac) I have only result

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: Yes, together into long line if I print $mac I have reuslt  111111222222333333444444555555666666777777888888999999101010101010111111111111121212121212131313131313 itd.

Comment: if I print $snr I have 33.433.533.133.232.931.834.534.834.534.134.132.731.932.131.931.831.530.631.031.331.131.131.030.133.733.733.533.533.332.932.632.732.532.332.031.334.734.8

Comment: That tells me nothing. You have to show the code that generated those variables, or I wont be able to help you.

Comment: Presumably you get those numbers one at the time. So then just add them to the hash like I showed one by one. `push @{ $hash{$mac} }, $snr;` What is the problem?

Comment: Yes one by one,the problem is that i do:  push @{ $hash{$mac} }, $snr;
        print(keys %hash,"\n"); I have 1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
itd I don't have unique keys I would like that key will be 1, 2,3 itd and in table six pomiar snr from another variable $snr

Comment: That is because you declare the hash inside the loop and print it inside the loop. You declare it before the loop, add to it during the loop, and print it after the loop. And print it with `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash`

Comment: Are you saying you can't modify the script that produces those values and have to parse its output?

Comment: Thank you, thanks to your help I was able to extract this information use Data::Dumper but now I have next problem how check lenght this hash array

Comment: @homcioq Set up a new question with the new info.

Comment: now I need to check in the loop whether the length of the list for individual keys is equal to 1, if so then print mac and snr

Answer (score 4):

You can just loop over the values, split the line, then use a push statement to add numbers to the hash value, like below. Note that I am using the infile handle `DATA` for simplicity here, you have to use your own file handle, or the `<>` operator.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($mac, $snr) = split;
    push @{ $hash{$mac} }, $snr;
}
print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
1 33,3 
1 33.2
1 33.3
1 32.7
1 32.9
1 32.5
1 31.7
2 34.4
2 34.9
2 34.6
2 34.3
2 33.5
2 30.8
3 31.9
3 32.0
3 31.8
3 31.7
3 31.4
3 30.4
95 34.8
96 30.6
96 31.8
96 33.4
96 34.2
96 34.0
96 29.5
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '3' => [
                   '31.9',
                   '32.0',
                   '31.8',
                   '31.7',
                   '31.4',
                   '30.4'
                 ],
          '1' => [
                   '33,3',
                   '33.2',
                   '33.3',
                   '32.7',
                   '32.9',
                   '32.5',
                   '31.7'
                 ],
          '2' => [
                   '34.4',
                   '34.9',
                   '34.6',
                   '34.3',
                   '33.5',
                   '30.8'
                 ],
          '96' => [
                    '30.6',
                    '31.8',
                    '33.4',
                    '34.2',
                    '34.0',
                    '29.5'
                  ],
          '95' => [
                    '34.8'
                  ]
        };
```

Comment: the problem is that the values ​​of both variables are obtained in a loop and so the variable mac goes every 6 snr values ​​up to 96 –

Comment: such values ​​are created in the loop
133.3133.5132.9133.1132.9131.8234.4233.7234.7230.3232.3230.8331.9332.0331.6331.6330.9330.2430.9431.3431.1431.1430.9430.

Comment: And the difference is...? You're going to have to be more clear about what you mean. Edit the question to add new info if you have it.